# Changing the dataframe headers and then interpolate in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, interpolation

I have the following data:

```
x = [-1.252054794520548, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

First I want to change the name of the columns of this dataframe, which is loaded from and CSV file:

```
df= pd.read_csv('df.csv', sep = ';')
df
    30/01/2016 29/02/2016 29/04/2016  29/01/2020
0    1,015538   0,643649   0,470071    0,225367   
1    0,796583   0,447712   0,337657    0,182079  
2    0,608432   0,348916   0,274036    0,17113
```

in a dataframe with the next headers:

```
    -1.252054794520548      -1.0        0.0        1.0
0        1,015538          0,643649   0,470071    0,225367   
1        0,796583          0,447712   0,337657    0,182079  
2        0,608432          0,348916   0,274036    0,17113
```

And then, with the new dataframe, interpolate a value in the header. For example, if I choose the value -0.7, the values should be between -1.0 and 0.0.
example:

```
x = -0.7
```

interpolate x in the headers to get the values interpolated:

```
values = [0.5, 0.4, 0.3] # This is the approximated output I expect that are the interpolated values
```

Is possible to do that? 
Any help would be perfect, even if you just know how to change the headers it would be great.
Thank you for taking your time in reading and trying to helping me

Comment: Headers are strings, not numbers, you probably need to do this your self with another intermediate array that holds the linear interpolation and then use the index in the 2D numpy array (I don't think the df is the proper structure for this).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the column names, simply do:

```
new_columns = [-1.252054794520548,-1.0,0.0,1.0]
df.columns = new_columns

print(df)
  -1.252055 -1.000000  0.000000  1.000000
0  1,015538  0,643649  0,470071  0,225367
1  0,796583  0,447712  0,337657  0,182079
2  0,608432  0,348916  0,274036   0,17113
```

If you want to perform any operations in the actual column names, do so prior to changing the actual column names, and set them afterwoods.

Comment: Thanks, but is possible that when I change the names, interpolate a value between two of them?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Please could you give me an example?

Comment: I want to get the values of the dataframe interpolated by giving a number x